# PHP Парсить текст по порядковому номеру

Tags: php

Есть такая строка

```
sedf
1. e
a e 5. r 2.d f 2. r
3.e f
4. rtt
2. d t 4. f
4. d
3. fd 
r
50.
```

Ее надо парсить на такие части чтобы каждая часть начал с порядкового номера. То есть первая часть от 1. до 2. , вторая от 2. до 3. 
И чтобы порядковый номер обязательно начал с нового строчка. И был продолжением предыдущего номера.

В итоге надо получить такой массив

```
array (

  0 => '1. e
a e 5. r 2.d f 2. r
3.e f
4. rtt',

  1 => '2. d t 4. f
4. d',

  2 => '3. fd 
r
50.',

)
```

Как можно решить эту задачу с помощью PHP?

Comment: лично мне не понятно, что в итоге нужно получить. У вас строка для поиска практически соответствует искомому значению. А ваше описание и вовсе "не привязано" к вашим примерам. Может быть попробуете переписать первый пост с вопросом?

Comment: я вот лично вижу только прерывание возрастающей последовательности 1-3-4, 2-4, 3-50 с помощью переноса строки. так что поддерживаю предыдущий коммент. Проясните свой вопрос.

Comment: Переписал пост.

Comment: Получаете регулярным выражением цифру в начале строки, перед точкой. прибавляете к ней 1. ищете второй регуляркой все от начала строки до второй цифры в начале строки. Вырезаете пролученную часть и кладете в выходной массив. Над остатком строки повторяете операцию. https://regex101.com/r/84lI6t/1